# Does a "straight", open-ended, infinite, but closed like a tube, have a name?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm trying to describe what would could be physically visualized as a tube (open ended, but closed if sliced in a specific plane). I know I'm not using the correct math terminology, but that's why I'm asking here.

Also, I'm interested to know if this concept extends to higher dimensions? I imagine so. The current description I have is "At least $N$ hyperplanes that intersect each other but create an infinite open ended tube, where $N$ is the number of dimensions".

Could you help me describe this more mathematically correct?

Edit: I'm also not sure if I'm using the word "tube" here mathematically correct either.

Comment: I would call in a "polygonal cylinder," or perhaps a "polygonal cylindrical surface."  I'm not sure if that is standard, but I think it would be generally understood.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question doesn't make any sense to me. What is "a “straight”, open-ended, infinite" thing that you wish to describe? Do you mean a cylindrical tube of infinite length? Could you explain the open and closed concepts you mention.

Comment: @DanielBuck, well, that's why I'm asking here, since I know I'm not using the right terminology. I'll try to explain it with an example. If I have three dimensions, the shape/surface/thing I'm trying to describe is at its basic created by three 2D planes that create an infinite "tube" with a triangle as its cross-section

Comment: @saulspatz, Thanks, I think that sounds like it makes sense. Does that description still applies for what I described in my previous comment?

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a cylinder or, perhaps, a cylinder with a polygonal base (at least, in the three dimensional case).  You could describe such an object as a Cartesian product, i.e. $B \times \mathbb{R}$, where $B$ is the base of the cylinder or the shape of a cross-section (i.e. a codimension 1 subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clearer. So kind of like an infinitely long triangular prism.

Comment: Well, in the case of your previous comment, I'd probably call it an "infinite triangular prism."

Comment: Maybe something to look at (but not visualize . . .) are [tube domains in several complex variables](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tube%22+%22several+complex+variables%22).